# How do I resize a bitmap to fit into a Windows button, in Dev C++?

Tags: c++, winapi

At the moment I am using the following code:

```
hwndB11 = CreateWindow ("BUTTON", "", 
   WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON | BS_BITMAP, 
   B11x, B11y, B11l, B11h, hwnd, (HMENU) BUTTON11,
   NULL, //((LPCREATESTRUCT) lParam)->hInstance,
   NULL);

SendMessage(hwndB11, 
   BM_SETIMAGE,
   IMAGE_BITMAP,
   (LPARAM)LoadBitmap(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(SWITCH_OFF)));
```

How do I modify the code so that the bitmap is stretched to fit onto a Windows button?  Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: You can use a library like GDI+ to resize the bitmap or use owner draw button

Comment: Generate a stretched bitmap and apply that to the button, whenever that button changes its size. You can create your stretched image using any algorithm you see fit, applying bi-cubic or bi-linear filtering, or point sampling, or dithering, and so on. Sample code is available at [Scaling an Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162950.aspx).